# Convert IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>> to array

Tags: c#, linq

Is there an easy way of converting `remaining` in the following code to a 1-D array.

```
var groups = data.OrderBy(d => d.Time).GroupBy(d => d.Period);
var first = groups.First().ToArray();
var remaining = groups.Skip(1).??
```

Comment: By calling `.ToArray()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var remaining = groups.Skip(1).SelectMany(g=>g).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SelectMany` to "flatten" a collection of collections:

```
var remaining = groups.Skip(1).SelectMany(d => d).ToArray();
```